# Eclipse editor tabs

Tags: eclipse, tabs

I have 2 projects with a few common files. 
So there are the linked resources pointing to a single physical file in each Eclipse project. The problem is, whenever I try to open these two files,the editor opens each file in a separate tab, it won't direct me to the already opened file.

It's very inconvenient generally. If I modify a file inside one tab and do build all then the changes are not applied to another project until I manually save the modified file. Options "save before building" does not help.

Does someone know what to do?

Comment: Are you allowing the workspace to automatically Refresh itself?

Comment: Yes, it's refreshed automatically

Comment: Do you know how to open the same file of two project in the same editor tab?

Comment: No, and I'm pretty sure that the abstraction that allows you to do this is supposed to be hidden from editors, truly treating them as separate files.